Is it possible to colour outer space black when the projection view contains both Earth and outer space in ggplot with sf data?
I am making a few maps of the USA and some of them contains both Earth and outer space due to the projection, as shown below:

It is generated by the code below:
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)


# Import Data:
df <- read_sf("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfortherestofus/book/refs/heads/main/data/states.geojson")

# Create the map:
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = df, fill = "grey90") +
  
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=ortho +lat_0=22.0 +lon_0=-162.5") +
  
  theme_minimal() +
  
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightblue")   # <- Set the colour for ocean
  )

I am just wondering if it is possible to colour outer space (highlighted) in black to reflect reality and also make the Earth, and therefore the USA, more distinguishable on the map?


One option would be to create a new sf object which is a grid covering the entire planet. You would need to transform that to your chosen projection and weed out the illegal panels. Thereafter you can simply plot it as a normal sf object:
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

seas <- st_polygon(list(cbind(c(seq(-180, 180, len = 100),
                                rep(0, 100),
                                seq(180, -180, len = 100),
                                rep(-180, len = 100)), 
                              c(rep(-90, 100),
                                seq(-90, 90, len = 100),
                                rep(90, 100),
                                seq(90, -90, len = 100))))) |>
  st_sfc(crs = "WGS84") |>
  st_sf() |>
  st_make_grid(n = c(200, 200)) |>
  st_transform(crs = "+proj=ortho +lat_0=22.0 +lon_0=-162.5")

val_st <- st_is_valid(seas)
seas <- seas[!is.na(val_st) & val_st]

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = seas, fill = "lightblue", col = "lightblue",
          linewidth = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = df, fill = "grey90") +
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=ortho +lat_0=22.0 +lon_0=-162.5",
           xlim = c(-513107, 6513107),
           ylim = c(-400000, 5000000)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
        panel.grid = element_blank())


Note that this covers up the latitude / longitude lines, but you can explicitly add them back in (without the annoying artefacts) by specifying a multilinestring:
latlon <- st_multilinestring(x = list(cbind(rep(-120, 100), 
                                            seq(0, 90, len = 100)),
                                      cbind(rep(-60, 100), 
                                            seq(0, 90, len = 100)),
                                      cbind(rep(-180, 100), 
                                            seq(0, 90, len = 100)),
                                      cbind(seq(-180, 0, len = 100),
                                            rep(10, 100)),
                                      cbind(seq(-180, 0, len = 100),
                                            rep(20, 100)),
                                      cbind(seq(-180, 0, len = 100),
                                            rep(30, 100)),
                                      cbind(seq(-180, 0, len = 100),
                                            rep(40, 100)),
                                      cbind(seq(-180, 0, len = 100),
                                            rep(50, 100)),
                                      cbind(seq(-180, 0, len = 100),
                                            rep(60, 100)),
                                      cbind(seq(-180, 180, len = 100),
                                            rep(70, 100)))) |>
  st_sfc(crs = "WGS84") |>
  st_sf() |>
  st_transform(crs = "+proj=ortho +lat_0=22.0 +lon_0=-162.5")

which results in
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = seas, fill = "lightblue", col = "lightblue",
          linewidth = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = df, fill = "grey90") +
  geom_sf(data = latlon, linewidth = 0.2, col = "gray50") +
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=ortho +lat_0=22.0 +lon_0=-162.5",
           xlim = c(-500000, 6000000),
           ylim = c(-400000, 5000000)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "black", linewidth = 1))


If you don't want to manually specify the co-ordinate limits you can get them from your sf object as follows:
crds <- df |> st_transform(crs = "+proj=ortho +lat_0=22.0 +lon_0=-162.5") |> 
  st_coordinates() |> 
  apply(2, range) 

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = seas, fill = "lightblue", col = "lightblue",
          linewidth = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = df, fill = "grey90") +
  geom_sf(data = latlon, linewidth = 0.2, col = "gray50") +
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=ortho +lat_0=22.0 +lon_0=-162.5",
           xlim = crds[,1],
           ylim = crds[,2]) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "black", linewidth = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_blank())


If you want more of a 3D appearance, the grid allows you to have an easy gradient fill, and I suppose you could add a gratuitous star field:
ggplot() +
  annotate("point", x = I(runif(300)), y = I(runif(300)), color = "white",
           alpha = runif(300), size = 0.3) +
  geom_sf(data = seas, aes(color = after_scale(fill),
            fill = sapply(seas[[1]], function(x) {
              sqrt(sum(colMeans(st_coordinates(x)[,1:2])^2))})),
          linewidth = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = latlon, linewidth = 0.2, col = "gray25") +
  geom_sf(data = df, fill = "#809060") +
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=ortho +lat_0=22.0 +lon_0=-162.5",
           xlim = crds[,1],
           ylim = crds[,2]) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "black", linewidth = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "lightblue", high = "deepskyblue4", guide = "none")



Nice nice! Cool Solution with the make grid. It's a little more difficult than I thought. I also worked on it and wanted to post my solution ;). Do you think it would be possible to automatically adjust the focus with 'coord_sf(xlim = c(-500000, 5600000), ylim = c(-700000, 5000000))' to be on the sf data present in df?

@G-Man Yes, your circular polygon is a big improvement to the grid. The graticules are also much easier, but we run into the problems of wonky projection if we use these (the unwanted horizontal lines). I guess you could strip the maximum and minimum points from the sf object with df |> st_transform(crs = "+proj=ortho +lat_0=22.0 +lon_0=-162.5") |> st_coordinates() |> apply(2, range) if you want an "auto-focus"

Cool solution, the autofocus makes it much easier to use! Hmm yes the horizontal lines are a bit ugly.

Thank you, Allan, that's an elegant solution. I’m just wondering if it’s possible to make a final tweak to place the latitude/longitude lines above the ocean and below the continent (as shown in the first picture from the question)? Many thanks

@Grasshopper_NZ yes - change the order of the geom_sf layers. Sea first, then lat-lon lines, then continent

@AllanCameron haha even with the starfield, you are a certified Legend. Even though I am missing some chinese spy balloons hovering over america ;)

The 3D and stars are perfect, thank you very much.

You can fake the sphere of the earth which is a bit faster ;) and then combine it with your geom_sf(data = df, fill = "grey90"). Doing this however will not automatically zoom in on America. So make sure to adjust xlim = c(-500000, 5600000), ylim = c(-700000, 5000000) to focus on the correct planet-section.
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(dplyr)
# Load the US states data

# Read the states GeoJSON
df <- read_sf("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfortherestofus/book/refs/heads/main/data/states.geojson")


# Define the CRS for orthographic projection
crs <- "+proj=ortho +lat_0=22.0 +lon_0=-162.5 "

# Create a spherical polygon using a large radius

# Create a large buffer to simulate a sphere
sphere <- st_buffer(st_sfc(st_point(c(-162.5, 22)), crs = 4326), dist = 10000000) %>%  # Adjust dist for larger/smaller spheres
  st_transform(crs = crs)

# Generate graticule lines (longitude and latitude lines)
graticule <- st_graticule(nlat = 15, nlong = 15) %>%  # Adjust nlat and nlong for density of lines
  st_transform(crs = crs)

# Plot the map
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = sphere, fill = "lightblue", alpha = 1) +  # Sphere
  geom_sf(data = graticule, color = "white", size = 0.5, alpha = 0.8) +  # Graticule (outside sphere)
  geom_sf(data = df, fill = "grey90") +  # States or regions
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-500000, 5600000), ylim = c(-700000, 5000000)) +  # Zoom to desired region
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
        panel.grid = element_blank())



@Grasshopper_NZ I updated my code so that the lines are now below the continents!
